# Not able to retrieve data from MySQL through flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm making a flask website app, I have connected a MySQL database but I'm not able to get the data into my HTML file. The data is supposed to show up in a side navigation but nothing is showing up(its blank). The purpose of this is to avoid hard coding text so that I can easily update pages that require the same text.

**These are my imports and setup**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'my_password_changed'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'swebsite'


mysql = MySQL(app)
```

**This is the function that is trying to retrieve the data** - *datas is printing correctly*

```
@app.route('/menu/internships')
def internships():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM professional")
    fetchdata = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    datas = []
    for i in range(len(fetchdata)):
        datas.append(fetchdata[i][1])
    # print(datas)
    return render_template('internships.html', data = datas)
```

**This is where I'm trying to use the data**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    {% for j in datas %}

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('professional')}}">Organisational Experience</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('internships')}}">{{j[0]}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('projects')}}">Projects & Research</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('respon')}}">Positions of Responsibility</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

---

---

I have updated my code, again nothing is printing on my screen

**This is the function that is trying to retrieve the data**

```
@app.route('/menu/internships')
def internships():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM professional")
    fetchdata = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    datas = {}
    # for j in fetchdata:
    datas['first'] = f"{fetchdata[0][1]}"
    datas['second'] = f"{fetchdata[1][1]}"
    datas['third'] = f"{fetchdata[2][1]}"
    datas['fourth'] = f"{fetchdata[3][1]}"

    print(datas)
    return render_template('internships.html', data = datas)
```

**This is where I'm trying to use the data**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    {% for j in data %}

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('professional')}}">{{j['first']}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('internships')}}">{{j['second']}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('projects')}}">{{j['third']}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('respon')}}">{{j['fourth']}}</a>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: You are passing "data" to your template, yet you are using "datas" in html. Either pass "`datas=datas`" or change html to `{% for j in data %}`

Comment: @Ehtesham Siddiqui Thank you but right now it's print multiple times on my screen, how can I assign values to a variable so that I print that instead? Currently its not accepting an equal to sign.

Comment: so you want to assign values in template ? use {% set %} from jinja2  
  https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#variables

Comment: or "g" https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing "data" to your template, yet you are using `"datas"` in html. Either pass `"datas=datas"` or change html to `{% for j in data %}`